# How to delete data in list view where its data came from the array list in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a button and when I click it I want to delete the value of arraylist first index, and yes the first index in the array list is deleted. But the data in my listview that came from my arraylist is not deleted.
**Here I got so far**

```
public ArrayList<String> imagesFileName = new ArrayList<String>();

 mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesFileName.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(FILE_NAME, filename[i]);
            map.put(DESCRIPTION, "desc");
            map.put(UPLOADEDBY, "uploadby");
            map.put(DATE_UPLOAD, "date_upload");
            map.put(ACTION, "delete");
            map.put(ID, String.valueOf(i));
            mylist.add(map);
    }


     adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mylist, R.layout.attribute_ireport_list, 
             new String[]{FILE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, UPLOADEDBY, DATE_UPLOAD, ACTION, ID},
             new int[]{R.id.tv_File, R.id.txt_Desc, R.id.tv_UploadedBy, R.id.tv_DateUploaded, R.id.tv_Action, R.id.txt_id}, true);

        lv_iReport.setAdapter(adapter);
    //code for delete of first index
    btn_Upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_Upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imagesFileName.remove(0);
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mylist, R.layout.attribute_ireport_list, 
                     new String[]{FILE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, UPLOADEDBY, DATE_UPLOAD, ACTION, ID},
                     new int[]{R.id.tv_File, R.id.txt_Desc, R.id.tv_UploadedBy, R.id.tv_DateUploaded, R.id.tv_Action, R.id.txt_id}, true);

                lv_iReport.setAdapter(adapter);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: After delete your item you have to call notifydatasetchanged() method for adapter

Comment: Also delete from mylist.

Comment: +1 for you @HirenDabhi. your excellent thanks dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 btn_Upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mylist.remove(0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use that :

```
myList.remove(object);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```